# Facebook share link - issues defining thumbnail image on iframe app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-like

I've created a simple Iframe app and attached it as a tab on my fanpage.

On this page I have a classic share link:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.fb-iframe-app-url.com">SHARE IT NOW!</a>
```

The iframe app is hosted on my server and here ive defined what usually works for images:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://domain.com/image.gif" />
```

However it seems all this kind of data, is fetched from the fanpage itself - which means I cant control those elements.

Do anyone have experience with customizing share thumbnail and text from within an iframe app-clicked share url?

Comment: This post was a while ago. Does anyone have tips on this?